# How do I move multiple files and add a .pgp extension?

Tags: bash, mv

I have 4 files in a directory, the mv command will not move all files AND add a .pgp extension.

I was hoping to keep this on the command line and not create a script.  Maybe I'm asking the question wrong on here/google.

4 files are in `/test/` - `test-1 test-2 test-3 test-4`

I've tried `mv /test/test* /test/dir/*.pgp` and it doesn't work because *.pgp is not a directory.

Is the only way to do this with a loop?  Also, would it have to be a for loop?  I'm very new to shell scripting and not very confident...

Comment: You could use simple bash `for` loop like so: `for i in test-1 test-2 test-3 test-4; do mv $i /test/dir/$i.pgp; done`

Comment: If test-1 thru -4 were the only files directory `/test` could i use the following?              
`for i in /test/* ; do mv $i /test/dir/$i.pgp`

Comment: Nevermind.... I just tried mine and no go...

Comment: It doesn't work because 1 - you missed the `done` part and 2 - you have to extract the file name via parameter expansion (that is, remove the leading path to avoid "no such file or directory" error) e.g. `mv "${i}" /test/dir/"${i##*/}.pgp"`

Comment: I was prompted with > and entered done, I forgot to mention that... but the second part you mentioned... it's over my head.  I never know when to use { } but I'll plug yours in and see.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the only way, but the best and simplest way is indeed a loop and preferably a for loop. It is trivial to do:

```
cd /test    
for file in test*; do
    mv "$file" /test/dir/"$file".pgp
done
```

That's it.

Comment: @Emile please see updated answer. My first version was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the files first, and then move them:

```
rename 's/(.*)/$1.pgp/' test*; mv test*.pgp /test/dir
```

Comment: Simpler first step: `rename 's/$/.pgp/' test*`.  (Note, though, we are using the perl version of rename and there are other incompatible `rename` utilities out there.)

Comment: how would i do this and be directory specific?  i.e. mv files from /test/ to /test/dir/

I don't understand the syntax exactly... is the . 'current directory' or a part of s?  ...I'm assuming s is the shortened sed command?

Comment: If you're using `perl-rename`, you may as well move them in a single command: `rename  's|^/test/|/test/dir/|; s/$/.pgp/' /test/test*`. No reason to do it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a loop, a for loop, is what should be used.

In two simple steps:

```
set -- test-{1..4}
for f; do mv "$f" "dir/$f.pgp"; done
```